# How to use protobuf-csharp-port to genetare multiple files from a single .proto file?

Tags: file, protocol-buffers

I use protobuf-csharp-port to generate a c# file for wp7.

My .protp file has many messages and finally generates a .cs file of about 100'000 lines. It's very large. I am wondering if i can generate a single .cs file for one single message.

I found the option csharp_multiple_files in old version of protobuf-csharp-port, and now it's gone. Can I still generate multiple files using the current version(2.3.0.277)? I also found option multiple_file in csharp_options.proto, but it's said the option is not currently honored.

I guess it can generate multiple files but i don't know how.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: given that this is generated code, not intended to be edited or even looked at, is it causing a *problem* in the single file? what is the *reason* you want this?

Comment: The generated source file is quite large. I just want to test if using smaller multiple files can has a better performance than a large single one in speed.

Comment: At most, that would affect the compiler performance (assuming we need it all), and the compiler has just about the same work to do no matter whether it is 1 file or 100. Well, OK, Visual Studio might behave differently, but *generally* you wouldn't have that file open so it wouldn't matter. Basically, I'm saying "that almost certainly won't make any difference".

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember, it's been a very long time since that option has actually worked. Making it work would have required significant effort, and as Marc implied it's almost always more convenient to generate a single file anyway. EDIT: As Marc noted, this is unlikely to have any speed implication. (It would *certainly* only be during development of course - it wouldn't affect the performance at execution time.) If it's taking a long time to build, you might want to *experiment* with putting the generated source into its own project; the C# compiler does some incremental compilation to avoid rebuilding files which haven't changed, I believe, but it's possible that it would work better at the project level.

I decided (or possibly one of my collaborators did) that it would be better to remove the option entirely as we didn't support it, rather than to keep it in there doing nothing. Without any firm reason to implement it, we didn't want to spend time making it work.

Apologies if you're one of the few for whom it makes sense - and patches welcome, of course - but I can't see us implementing it any time soon.

You could use multiple .proto files, of course, with imports (so long as you can avoid cycles).